# How to require the existence of a function in a constraint?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I have a file `vector.h` with a custom `Vector` class, where the data type of the vector entries should be restricted to types for which a function `f` is implemented:

```
template <typename T>
concept Vector_Type = requires (T a) {
    f(a);
};

template <Vector_Type T>
class Vector {};
```

Additionally, I have multiple files where the function `f` is defined for different data types, e.g. the following `datatype_int.h` header file:

```
int f(int a) { return 2*a; }
```

If I include `datatype_int.h` after `vector.h`, the compiler complains that the constraint is not satisfied:

```
#include "vector.h"
#include "datatype_int.h"

int main() {
    Vector<int> v;  // Error: constraints not satisfied

    return 0;
}
```

This is not a very helpful error message and I would like to avoid being dependent on the order of the includes. However, there is no way to declare the function `f` for all possible data types `T` in `vector.h`, since I do not know which data types will be used.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think there's a way around this. For instantiations of `Vector` with class types, the concept should find the appropriate `f` via ADL, but to work with built-in types, I think you have no choice but to declare `f` before the concept definition.

Comment: I am surprised to hear that what I intend to do actually works with class types. I just tested it and it worked perfectly fine. What is the reason for this difference between class types and built-in types? This already solves my problem for the most part.

Comment: It has to do with ADL. For `f`s taking class types, ADL will look up all `f`s in associated namespaces, so it works. ADL doesn't apply like that to in-built types, and so the declarations you want to find need to be declared lexically before the point at which you need lookup to happen.

Comment: Now that I think about it some more, this may be solvable with modules instead of textual includes, but I don't know enough about modules or how ADL interacts with that to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure how workable this design is, but the crux of the issue is that `int` is a builtin type. If you have a special type that is used to invoke `f`, you'll be able to delay the lookup of `f` until instantiation.

For example:

```
struct enabler{};

template <typename T>
concept Vector_Type = requires (T a) {
    f(a, enabler{});
};

template <Vector_Type T>
class Vector {};

int f(int a, enabler = {}) { return 2*a; }

int main() {
    Vector<int> v; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks quite reasonable, though you should default the second argument of `f`, i.e. `int f(int a, enabler = {})` so callers of `f` don't have to worry about that implementation detail.